# Single item of list as a multiline string

Tags: python, list, multilinestring

I am working with Python. I want to convert a single item list to a multiline string.

I fetched the email string from a database. All emails are stored as a list item (between ' ').

emails strings are have special-characters and also symbols like[ ' " , @  (  *  &  # ]
When I fetch list items(emails) ONE-BY-ONE at that time my string is stored in ' ' so when 'it comes in a string at that time string is broken into multiple parts.

So, I want to store one list item (email) as a multiline string(''' ''').

```
string=[]

for row in email_records:
    string.append(row[1])

print(string)



output get like this:-
['d "jkssjfdsd<sdsdfg @flkj'dlkj'hcjkhkg d#cgcgcg/jcgj'jjjx dfdffh# \fjhfghjj',
 'd "jkssjfdsd<sdsdfg @flkj'dlkj'hcjkhkg d#cgcgcg/jcgj'jjjx dfdffh# \fjhfghjj',
 'd "jkssjfdsd<sdsdfg @flkj'dlkj'hcjkhkg d#cgcgcg/jcgj'jjjx dfdffh# \fjhfghjj',
 'd "jkssjfdsd<sdsdfg @flkj'dlkj'hcjkhkg d#cgcgcg/jcgj'jjjx dfdffh# \fjhfghjj']
```

I fetch all items one-by-one and find substring at that time it is not working because when **'** is comes in string at that time string is broken in to multiple parts.

```
    for massage in string:
        print(massage)

output get like this:-
'd "jkssjfdsd<sdsdfg @flkj'dlkj'hcjkhkg d#cgcgcg/jcgj'jjjx dfdffh# \fjhfghjj'


output wont like this:-
'''d "jkssjfdsd<sdsdfg @flkj'dlkj'hcjkhkg d#cgcgcg/jcgj'jjjx dfdffh# \fjhfghjj'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, the `print` command prints the string (or `str(obj)`) without the `'`s.

However, you can print them yourself:

```
for massage in string:
    print(f"'''{massage}'''")
```

Comment: I don't want to only print I want to give attributes of multiline-string. so I used                    
for massage in string :
    print(f'''{massage}''')                                                                                                                            but your answer very helpful for find my answer.